# Permutations to un-shuffle indistinguishable cards from multiple decks?

Tags: matrices, permutations, modular-arithmetic

An "out-shuffle" on a deck of size $2n$ is defined by the permutation $O$, where $$O = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 2  & \cdots & n-1 && n && n+1 && \cdots && k && \cdots &&2n-1\\
0 & 2 & 4  & \cdots & 2n-2 && 1 && 3 && \cdots && 2k\pmod{2n-1} && \cdots && 2n-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Observe that if $2^x\equiv 1\pmod{2n-1}$, then after $x$ out-shuffles the deck will be restored to its original position. A popular example of this is using a deck of 52 cards (i.e. $2n=52$), it will take 8 out-shuffles to cycle the deck back to the starting position since $2^8=256\equiv1\pmod{51}$.

Now for my question:

Assume you have a stack of $n$ black tickets and a stack of $n$ white tickets. Note these tickets have no distinct markers, and so the $n$ black tickets are indistinguishable from each other (and similarly for the $n$ white tickets). Now place one deck on top of the other to create a combined deck of size $2n$.

From the above, we know there is a smallest, non-trivial $x$ where $2^x\equiv1\pmod{2n-1}$ such that $x$ out-shuffles restores the deck back to the *exact* original position. But is there a number $y<x$ such that $y$ out-shuffles will sift the large stack into the 2 distinct black and white smaller stacks?

I think the answer is "no" and that I'd have to use a proof by contradiction.

However maybe it's possible with an "in-shuffle"? An "in-shuffle" on a deck of size $2n$ is defined by the permutation $I$, where:

$$I = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2   & \cdots & n && n+1 && n+2 && \cdots && k && \cdots &&2n\\
2 & 4  & \cdots & 2n && 1 && 3 && \cdots && 2k\pmod{2n+1} && \cdots && 2n-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Similar to the out-shuffle, observe that if $2^z \equiv 1 \pmod{2n+1}$, then after $z$ in-shuffles the deck will be restored to its original position. In the case of the deck of a deck of 52 cards (i.e. $2n=52$), it will take $z=52$ in-shuffles to cycle the deck back to the starting position since $2^{52}\equiv1\pmod{53}$ (by [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermats_little_theorom)).

One difference, however, is that with the in-shuffle, there is an opportunity for the deck to be completely *reversed* (if $z$ is even, then by symmetry this means that $\dfrac{z}{2}$ in-shuffles reverses the deck). For the ticket stack problem posed, this would satisfy sifting the stack back into 2 distinct black and white stacks using $\frac{z}{2}$ in-shuffles (which is of course fewer than $z$ in-shuffles).

But this is a pretty unique case ($z$ must be even and we must be using in-shuffles).

Comment: In the out-shuffle case, there is no way the colors will switch. This is because the bottom ticket stays in the same position in an out-shuffle.

Comment: Did you mean to say $z = 52$ in-shuffles near the end?

Comment: Running a program confirms that there is no $y < x$ for $n < 1000$ such that it separates the piles (in the case of an out-shuffle).

Comment: Yes, sorry I fixed it now ($z=52$ not 51). Also I was mistaken: $z$ isn't *always* even...  It's clear a deck of $2n=6$ cards requires $z=3$ in-shuffles to restore the deck back to the original position (and 3 is odd, not even).So there's no "reverse" or "sifted" deck to speak of. Thanks for running the program. It just feels weird since so often in probability removing the constraint of distinguishing factors often improves the probability substantially. Guess not in this case!